# How to set a textfield text from main method in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield, program-entry-point

I am new to [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) (but not Java) and I have a problem. I have created a GUI with NetBeans, which contains only a [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) and a [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html).

I want to add text to the textfield from the main method, so I added the following line to the end of the main method (so basically in the main method the generated code creates the [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), and only after that comes my extra line): `jTextField1.setText("WHATEVER");`
And nothing happens. I have changed the textfield to `public static`, but still nothing.

However, if I use the same line within the `actionPerformed` method of the button, it works.

Why? Why can't I set the text from the main class?

Here is the code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
  */
 package pac.jframe_test;

  /**
  *
  * @author Orand
  */
public class JFrame_Test_UI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form JFrame_Test_UI
 */
public JFrame_Test_UI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(154, 154, 154)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(112, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 185, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(103, 103, 103))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(109, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(96, 96, 96)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(52, 52, 52))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText("whatever");
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame_Test_UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame_Test_UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame_Test_UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame_Test_UI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JFrame_Test_UI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    jTextField1.setText("WHATEVER");
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
public static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `jTextField1` variable is not initialized yet at the moment you try to set its text. Indeed, it's only initialized t=when the event queue calls the runnable passed toinvokeLater at the end of the main method.

Moreover, you're accessing a Swing component from the main thread, and Swing components must only be used from the event disptach thread. That's why, BTW, the main method initializes the frame inside a runnable passed to `EventQueue.invokeLater()`. Please read the [Swing tutorial about concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), or your next question will ask why sleeping in an event listener freezes the whole GUI.

This field should not be public, and it should even less be static. Why don't you initialize the field's text from the frame constructor? That's where it should be initialized.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot initialize from the constructor. The problem is actually more complex than this, because I have created this program only as a test, to find the answer why my main project is not working.

Comment: Then add a setText() method to your frame, which sets the text in the text field, and call it from the event dispatch thread, using code similar to the code at the end of the main method (`EventQueue.invokeLater()` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`)

Comment: My main project will be a terminal for serial ports. I have there a combobox which should list the available ports. There is an other class, in which a method first counts the ports then creates an array and puts the port names in there. Then the array is read by the combobox, thus it will be filled. Since I do not know the number of ports and the port names, I cannot initialize the combobox. So that was the whole reason I tried using the main method. And I do not know how to solve the problem. Because the first thing that should run to initilize the combobox is the method from the other class

Comment: Oh, well. I was a retard or something. I managed to solve it. I mean in the main project, so this thing with the textfiled is not needed anymore. I am very grateful for your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to netbeans code architecture, it calls the **initComponents()** method from the default construction of your Class that extends JFrame, so the **memory allocation** of all the **JComponents**, that you are using in your code would be done in **initComponents** method body. so it is recommended to call any method of these JComponents after the  **initComponents** method call.

your code should be like that....

```
public JFrame_Test_UI() {
    initComponents();
    jTextField1.setText("WHATEVER");    
}
```